# have error to get data in json format in my android app

Tags: php, android, json, web-services

i'm try to send id and get data in json format from mysql db with php in android.
at first when i send id,all data recieve to my app.and app shows them.

```
<?php
require_once('Connection.php');
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8mb4');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT id,username,password,role FROM images WHERE id = $id ;";
$result2=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$response=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
    array_push($response,array("id"=>$row[0],
                                "username"=>$row[1],
                                "password"=>$row[2],
                                "role"=>$row[3]));
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8'); 
    print json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

[image]

but when i ask same data with username and my php stil works fine.

[image]

but my app cant get data and makes error ** json parsing error:Value

here is my android code for send username and get data

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    ///////////////////////////////
    HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

    String link;
    String data="";
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    String result;

    try {

        data = "?username=" + URLEncoder.encode("david", "UTF-8");

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    url4 = "http://************/score.php" + data;
    jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url4);
    //toast(url4);
    //toast(jsonStr);
    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONArray contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                user_id = c.getString("id");
                user_name=c.getString("username");
                user_pass=c.getString("password");
                user_role=c.getString("role");

                //score=c.getString("score");
                contact = new HashMap<>();
                contact.put("id", user_id);
                contact.put("username", user_name);
                contact.put("password", user_pass);
                contact.put("role", user_role);

                // adding contact to contact list
                contactList.add(contact);
            }

        } catch (final JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
        });
    }
    return null;
```

where is my problem

Comment: Can you please post the response which you are receiving from the API. Also, please post the LogCat output for quick debugging.

Comment: i put response api image above and i cant put logcat bc myandroidstudio avd doesnt have internet connection so i try in my android device

Comment: can you add your stacktrace (logcat output) please

Comment: my android studio avd doesnt have internet so i try in my android phone

Comment: You can connect your device to your pc and select it in your Android Studio's drop down menu in Logcat view.

Comment: Sending password over the wire is almost never a good idea